# form action for view that serve multiple routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

In my mvc 4 application there is a view that serve request for both "Add" and "Edit" operations, and the routes for both request's are as follows:

for Add operation:

```
"ItemAdd", Item/Add, new {controller = "Item", action = "ItemAddEdit"}
```

for Edit operation:

```
"ItemEdit", Item/Edit/{ItemID}, new {controller = "Item", action = "ItemAddEdit"}
```

And in the view i use following helper to render the form tag:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ItemAddEdit", "Item", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id="main-form" }))
```

now the problem is in both "Add" and "Edit" cases form action attribute is same like

how can i change the form action attribute with respect to route.

Comment: Do you have another POST action named `ItemAddEdit()`? Its not clear what you trying to achieve with this? If your passing a parameter for `ItemID` it will be added to the forms `action` attribute

Comment: Please let us know what you clearly want to achieve Please put your controller code for "ItemAdd" and "ItemEdit".

Answer (score 0):

well the problem is solved.

i just change the order of routes in the route registration file and every thing work's fine.

```
"ItemEdit", Item/Edit/{ItemID}, new {controller = "Item", action = "ItemAddEdit"}
"ItemAdd", Item/Add, new {controller = "Item", action = "ItemAddEdit"}
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the controller name from the form helper

`@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id="main-form" }))`